# Postgres 9.3 end-of-copy marker corrupt - Any way to change this setting?

Tags: sql, postgresql, awk

I am trying to stream data through an AWK program to a Postgres COPY command.  This works great usually.  However, in my data recently I have been getting long text stings containing '\.' values.

Postgres Documentation mentions this combination of characters represents the end-of-data marker, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html, and I am getting the associated errors when trying to insert with COPY.

My question is, is there a way to turn this off?  Perhaps change the end-of-data marker to a different combination of characters?  Or do I have to alter/remove these strings before trying to insert using the COPY command?

Comment: Consider adding small sample good/bad data to your question using `{}` edit tool at top left of edit box. Hard to visualize your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Do note that the `\.` must be single on a line, such that the "\n\\.\n" pattern occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to filter your data through `sed 's:\\:\\\\:g'` - this would change every `\` in your data to `\\`, which is a correct escape sequence for single backslash in copy data.

But I think not only backslash would be problematic. Also newlines should be encoded by `\n`, carriage returns as `\r` and tabs as `\t` (tab is a default field delimiter in copy).

Comment: The file is tab delimited, so that won't work.  But I agree this type of approach will work.  However, I am hoping there is a way to tell Postgres to use a different end-of-data marker instead of '\.'.  I would prefer to not alter the data at all if I don't have to.

Comment: So far I haven't found a setting that can change the end-of-data marker string, and from the responses I have seen here, it seems that this might not be possible.  That being said the approach in this answer is going to work the best for my issue.  I used a slightly different script, `awk '{gsub(/\\+\./,"..", $0)}{print}'`, and am replacing each '\.' with '..'.

Comment: any suggestion , pointers,                                                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414536/multiple-column-copy-format-postgresql-node-js